Checking if authentication in required on a page using Rails and Devise
I have a Rails 6.1 application that uses Devise for authentication.
In my application_controller.rb I by default require authentication on all pages:
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    before_action :authenticate_user!, unless: :devise_controller?
    ...
end

On pages I do not want authentication to be required I add a skip.
class ControllerWithoutAuthentication
    skip_before_action :authenticate_user!
end

I have a header I want to add just to the pages where authentication is required.  How can I check this?
I have tried the helper below, but it doesn't seem to handle the skip correctly:
module ApplicationHelper
  def authentication_required?
    user_auth_required = action_auth_required?(:authenticate_user!)

    (user_auth_required && !action_skipped?(:authenticate_user!))
  end

  private

  def action_auth_required?(auth_method)
    controller_class._process_action_callbacks.any? do |callback|
      callback.filter == auth_method && callback.kind == :before
    end
  end

  def action_skipped?(auth_method)
    controller_class._process_action_callbacks.any? do |callback|
      callback.filter == auth_method && callback.kind == :skip_before && action_matches?(callback)
    end
  end

  def action_matches?(callback)
    only = Array(callback.instance_variable_get(:@options)[:only])
    except = Array(callback.instance_variable_get(:@options)[:except])

    (only.empty? || only.include?(controller.action_name.to_sym)) &&
    !except.include?(controller.action_name.to_sym)
  end

  def controller_class
    controller.class
  end
end


I'd suggest making a separate base controller class for unauthenticated pages that includes the skip logic.  Then you can just check using is_a? on the controller. Conversely, I usually create a secured controller that does auth, and use that for authenticated pages.  But in either case, it saves you from having to repeat on every controller.

@dbugger I'm not a fan of that approach as the whole point is that controller actions should explicitly opt of authentication so that you don't create a security hole by omission. That's worth repeating yourself for.

@max - if all my controllers inherit from a secure controller then I am less likely to have a hole than remembering to do each one individually

@dbugger yes, what I advocating is that you OPT OUT explicitly rather than accidentially leaving an action open because someone used the wrong superclass.

The simplest possible solution would be to just override the helper method provided by Devise:
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  # ...
  def authenticate_user!
    headers['Header-Name'] = 'header value'
    super
  end
end

If you want to get fancy create your own callbacks:
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  define_callbacks :authenticate
  # ...
  def authenticate_user!
    run_callbacks :authenticate do
      super
    end
  end
end

class FooController < ApplicationController 
  set_callback :authenticate, :after do
    headers['Header-Name'] = 'header value'
  end
end

If you want an even more fancy solution look into the hooks provided by Warden.
